# Can not upload file, does not see file

Tags: php

I need to upload file to folder and after send it via phpmailer. I have problem with upload. It does not see `$_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]` and on `var_dump` of it shows `NULL`. Also shows dir `C:\fakepath`, I read that it is security side. How to avoid this problem and upload file?

```
<form method="post" action="example.php" name="example" id="example" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" class="form-control" name="file_name" id="file_name" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit_btn" name="submit_btn" />
</form>
```

**EXAMPLE.PHP**

```
$uploads_dir = '/uploads'; 

$tmp_name = $_FILES["file_name"]["tmp_name"]; 
$uploadedFile = $uploads_dir ."/". basename($_FILES['file_name']['name']."test");

function isAllowedFile($filename)
{
    $allowed = array(".pdf", ".png", ".jpg", ".jpeg");
    $extension = strtolower(substr($filename, strripos($filename, '.')));
    if(in_array($extension, $allowed)){return TRUE;}else{return FALSE;}
}

if(isset($_FILES["file_name"]) && $_FILES["file_name"]["error"] == 0 && isAllowedFile($_FILES["file_name"]["name"]))
{

  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile))  { 
  //do smth 
  }
  else { 
  var_dump($_POST);
  }
}
```

```js
$('#example').submit(function() {
  var action = $(this).attr('action');
  $("#message").show(400, function() {
    $('#message').hide();

    $('#submit')
      .after('<img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" class="loader" />')
      .attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    $.post(action, {
        surname: $('#surname').val(),
        allnames: $('#allnames').val(),
        dateofbirth: $('#dateofbirth').val(),
        country: $('#country').val(),
        birthplace: $('#birthplace').val(),
        sexselect: $('#sexselect').val(),
        telefon: $('#telefon').val(),
        mobile: $('#mobile').val(),
        addressperm: $('#addressperm').val(),
        email: $('#email').val(),
        passnumb: $('#passnumb').val(),
        paspisuedate: $('#paspisuedate').val(),
        paspexpdate: $('#paspexpdate').val(),
        file_name: $('#file_name').val(),
        residadress: $('#residadress').val(),
        visitkarab: $('#visitkarab').val()
      },
      function(data) {
        document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = data;
        $('#message').slideDown('slow');
        $('#example img.loader').fadeOut('slow', function() {
          $(this).remove()
        });
        $('#submit').removeAttr('disabled');
        //if(data.match('success') != null) $('#contactformvisa').slideUp(3000);

      });
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: check your apache error log.your code works fine it produce this result in my local  string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/php8zJlru"

Comment: @NanThiyagan there are no errors(

Answer (score 0):

You must put the complete address in the `$uploads_dir` variable. It looks like you are trying this on a windows system, so there won't be a `/uploads` directory. You should put address like `C:/directory`. Make sure that you have enabled read/write/delete permission for the PHP user on that directory. Also please note that you are populating `$uploadedFile` var like this:

`$uploadedFile = $uploads_dir . basename($_FILES['file_name']['name']."test");`

like this:

`$uploadedFile = $uploads_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES['file_name']['name']."test");`

There should be a slash between the folder name and filename.

**Edit**: The issue is that you are trying to submit the form using jQuery by getting the file path using `$('#file_name').val()`. According to HTML 5 specifications, you can't get the location of the file using JS. It is mentioned in [this blog](https://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/the-mystery-of-cfakepath-unveiled/), which explained:

```
According to the specifications of HTML5, a file upload control should not reveal the real local path to the file you have selected, if you manipulate its value string with JavaScript. Instead, the string that is returned by the script, which handles the file information is C:\fakepath.

This requirement is already implemented in Internet Explorer 8 - the real path to the file will be shown only if the page that contains the control is added to the trusted sites collection of the browser.
```

So, to submit the form using ajax, you can use the `FormData` object as mentioned at [this link](http://phppot.com/php/php-ajax-image-upload/).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $("#example").on('submit', (function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: "example.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: new FormData(this),
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#targetLayer").html(data);
                },
                error: function(jqHXR, status, error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
        }));
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$uploadedFile = $uploads_dir . "/"` fixed that, thanx, but still nothing works(
And it is not on local, i am testing code on my web hosting. and `$uploads_dir` i changed to `/home/my_username/public_html/uploads` and still nothing

Comment: have you given write permission to the `uploads` folder? Try setting the permission to 777.

Comment: Yes, I tried. I did `var_dump($_POST)` and it shows me `C:\fakepath\my picture_name.jpg`. In my opinion problem is that it can not read `$_FILES['file_name']['tmp_name']` and show is null or browser security hide it

Comment: try `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: `array(0) { }` as i said, does not see file to upload.

Comment: Are you trying to submit the form via ajax?

Comment: After submit i am checking `form` for val() by jquery. I u need i can add code also. here is short one on submit i am checking post. `$.post(action, {file_name: $('#file_name').val()},`

Comment: That's the problem. Try submitting the form normally, without using jQuery.

Comment: Okay, it is working if i do not use ajax. Are there any way to do it with ajax?

Comment: Okay. You may want to check the details here:
http://phppot.com/php/php-ajax-image-upload/
The thing is, you can't get the file path using `$('#file_name').val()` method. Even if you get it, the file won't be submitted. Instead, you can submit a FormData objected created with the form values as mentioned in the link.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please mark it as correct if it helped.

Comment: What is **targetLayer** there? I need to pass approx. 10 string data and 1 file

Comment: It is the id of the div which will show the output of the example.php file. You can remove that line if you don't want to get any response back. And it will automatically submit all the fields from the form.

Comment: It is not working for me, not reaching the file example.php

Comment: I've updated my answer and included code in the error callback. Please try the new code and see if you are getting any error.

Comment: Are there any way to submit form using jquery? Cuz i wrote many line of codes which will work after submit and file upload) if not `$('#file_name').val()`, are there anothe approach?

Comment: This is using jQuery to submit the form. [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) is a jQuery function. Please share the code you are using and I'll update it to work with this.

Comment: I added small main part of jquery code (on my question part), that submit form, use loading annimation and shows content at the end of loading. Is it possible to modify it to make it work? Ok, i understand that i can not use `$('#file_name').val()`, but what can I use instead of this code?

Comment: I would suggest you put all the input fields inside the image uploader form so you can use the `new FormData(this);` functionality without any modification. That will greatly reduce the amount of code you are using. This will be your final code then: https://pastebin.com/bPzbTSL9

Comment: all my inputs are in 1 form(file inpute also). So on submit i still use jquery and used your jquery code. But it is not working, I see that u make code shorter, what should I add or change there?

Answer (score 0):

It looked, to me, that there was an issue with the declaration of `$uploadedFile` using `basename($_FILES['file_name']['name']."test")` ~ this would result in the file having no extension when saved.

The `isAllowedFile` can be simplified a little by using `pathinfo` to get the file extension rather than a complicated use of `substr`

The directory structure you have on your webserver is unknown but if you assume that the document root is `c:/wwwroot/html/public` then you would typically upload files outside of this to a non-public directory, such as `c:/wwwroot/html/uploads` ~ so with that in mind the directory used would be `c:/wwwroot/html/uploads/`

---

**Upload form**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>File Upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form method='post' action='example.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
          <input type='file' class='form-control' name='file_name' id='file_name' required>
          <input id='bttn_sub' type='submit' value='Standard Submit' />
          <input id='bttn_ajax' type='button' value='AJAX submit' />
          <output id='fb'></output>
        </form>
        <script>
            var bttn=document.getElementById('bttn_ajax');
            bttn.onclick=function(e){
                var xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                var fd=new FormData( this.parentNode );
                xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )document.getElementById('fb').innerHTML=this.response;
                }
                xhr.open( 'POST', 'example.php', true );
                xhr.send( fd );
            }.bind( bttn );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**example.php**

```
<?php
    $fieldname='file_name';

    function isAllowedFile( $ext ){
        $allowed = array( 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg' );
        return in_array( $ext , $allowed );
    }

    function createpath( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
        if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
            createpath( dirname( $path ) );
            mkdir( $path, $perm, TRUE );
            clearstatcache();
        }
        return $path;
    }

    if( isset( $_FILES[ $fieldname ] ) ){

        $obj=(object)$_FILES[ $fieldname ];

        $name=$obj->name;
        $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
        $size=$obj->size;
        $error=$obj->error;


        if( is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) && $error==UPLOAD_ERR_OK ){


            $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            chdir( $root );
            chdir( '../' );

            $uploads_dir = createpath( getcwd() . '/uploads/' );


            $uploadedFile = $uploads_dir . $name;
            $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

            if( isAllowedFile( $ext ) ){

                $status = move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $uploadedFile );

                if( $status ){
                    //do smth 
                    echo "OK";
                } else {
                    var_dump($_POST);
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

I tried the above demo - I had missed a `$` from `uploadedFile` but when that was corrected it worked fine - note I used a path pertinent to my pc `c:/temp/fileuploads/`

---

Consider the following when trying to navigate to the upload directory:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir( $root );
print_r( getcwd() );

chdir( '../' );
print_r( getcwd() );
```

This finds the server root and navigates up one level, from there ( if you store files outside of root ) you can then use `getcwd()` to form part of the target path

```
function createpath( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
    if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
        createpath( dirname( $path ) );
        mkdir( $path, $perm, TRUE );
        clearstatcache();
    }
    return $path;
}
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
chdir( $root );
chdir( '../' );

$uploads_dir = createpath( getcwd() . '/uploads/' );
```

Comment: Problem is that it does not find file, does nto enter to first if `if( isset( $_FILES[ $fieldname ] ) )`

Comment: In my opinion i have different problem. First of all, code does not enter to first `if`, it does not see file.  Secondly, that path `c:/temp/fileuploads/`, problem that u r checking on you local, but if u check on any web hosting server, you will get `C:\fakepath\your_file_name`. it is not passing my file by post to next stage

Comment: we don't know the file system on your webserver - you need to determine what that would be or where you intend to store files ( in document root or outside )

Comment: I will add a little helper above

Comment: I read below that you are using ajax(jQuery) yet that does not appear anywhere in the question.... is this the case?

Comment: `chdir( $root );` it shows right, eve i added `$root ."/uploads";. everything useless, it does not see file. IDK why it is not reach to that page

Comment: Yes, I use jquery to check post data. Is problem in that? Now i am trying to write code in one page, with if else, will try to catch file in same page

Comment: Okay, it is working if i do not use ajax. Are there any way to do it with ajax?

Comment: modified the above html page - two methods now: Standard form submit and also ajax upload using `FormData` ~ no jQuery as I do not use it...